# revealing clusters of interaction in igraph

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I have an interaction network and I used the following code to make an adjacency matrix and subsequently calculate the dissimilarity between the nodes of the network and then cluster them to form modules:

```
ADJ1=abs(adjacent-mat)^6
dissADJ1<-1-ADJ1
hierADJ<-hclust(as.dist(dissADJ1), method = "average")
```

Now I would like those modules to appear when I plot the igraph.

```
g<-simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjacent-mat, weighted=T))
plot.igraph(g)
```

However the only thing that I have found thus far to translate hclust output to graph is as per the following tutorial: http://gastonsanchez.com/resources/2014/07/05/Pretty-tree-graph/

```
phylo_tree = as.phylo(hierADJ)
graph_edges = phylo_tree$edge
graph_net = graph.edgelist(graph_edges)
plot(graph_net)
```

[image]

which is useful for hierarchical lineage but rather I just want the nodes that closely interact to cluster as follows:

[image]

Can anyone recommend how to use a command such as components from igraph to get these clusters to show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

igraph provides a bunch of different [layout algorithms](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/layout) which are used to place nodes in the plot.

A good one to start with for a weighted network like this is the [force-directed layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) (implemented by `layout.fruchterman.reingold` in igraph).

Below is a example of using the force-directed layout using some simple simulated data.

First, we create some mock data and clusters, along with some "noise" to make it more realistic:

```
library('dplyr')
library('igraph')
library('RColorBrewer')

set.seed(1)

# generate a couple clusters
nodes_per_cluster <- 30
n <- 10

nvals <- nodes_per_cluster * n

# cluster 1 (increasing) 
cluster1 <- matrix(rep((1:n)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# cluster 2 (decreasing)
cluster2 <- matrix(rep((n:1)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# noise cluster
noise <- matrix(sample(1:2, nvals, replace=TRUE) +
                rnorm(nvals, sd=1.5),
                nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

dat <- rbind(cluster1, cluster2, noise)
colnames(dat) <- paste0('n', 1:n)
rownames(dat) <- c(paste0('cluster1_', 1:nodes_per_cluster), 
                   paste0('cluster2_', 1:nodes_per_cluster),
                   paste0('noise_',    1:nodes_per_cluster))
```

Next, we can use [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) to construct our adjacency matrix:

```
# create correlation matrix
cor_mat <- cor(t(dat))

# shift to [0,1] to separate positive and negative correlations
adj_mat <- (cor_mat + 1) / 2

# get rid of low correlations and self-loops
adj_mat <- adj_mat^3
adj_mat[adj_mat < 0.5] <- 0
diag(adj_mat) <- 0
```

Cluster the data using `hclust` and `cutree`:

```
# convert to dissimilarity matrix and cluster using hclust
dissim_mat <- 1 - adj_mat

dend <- dissim_mat %>% 
    as.dist %>% 
    hclust

clusters = cutree(dend, h=0.65)

# color the nodes
pal = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"))(length(unique(clusters)))
node_colors <- pal[clusters]
```

Finally, create an igraph graph from the adjacency matrix and plot it using the `fruchterman.reingold` layout:

```
# create graph
g <- graph.adjacency(adj_mat, mode='undirected', weighted=TRUE)

# set node color and plot using a force-directed layout (fruchterman-reingold)
V(g)$color <- node_colors
coords_fr = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g, weights=E(g)$weight)

# igraph plot options
igraph.options(vertex.size=8, edge.width=0.75) 

# plot network
plot(g, layout=coords_fr, vertex.color=V(g)$color)
```

In the above code, I generated two "clusters" of correlated rows, and a third group of "noise".

Hierarchical clustering (`hclust` + `cuttree`) is used to assign the data points to clusters, and they are colored based on cluster membership.

The result looks like this:

[image]

For some more examples of clustering and plotting graphs with igraph, checkout: http://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/LearnROnYourOwn/code/igraph.html

Comment: Thank you so much these graphs look really informative my experience isn't high enough that I would be able to produce something like this before my deadlines but I may try to contact you to send some example data

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shared some toy data for us to play with and suggest improvements to code, but your question states that you are only interested in plotting your clusters distinctly - that is, graphical presentation.

Although `igraph` comes with some nice [force directed layout algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing), such as `layout.fruchterman.reingold`, `layout_with_kk`, etc., they can, in presence of a large number of nodes, quickly become difficult to interpret and make sense of at all.

Like this:

[image]

With these traditional methods of visualising networks,

- the layout algorithms, rather than the data, determine the visualisation
- similar networks may end up being visualised very differently
- large number of nodes will make the visualisation difficult to interpret

Instead, I find [Hive Plots](http://www.hiveplot.net/) to be better at displaying important network properties, which, in your instance, are the cluster and the edges.

[image]

In your case, you can:

- Plot each cluster on a different straight line
- order the placement of nodes intelligently, so that nodes with certain properties are placed at the very end or start of each straight line
- Colour the edges to identify direction of edge

To achieve this you will need to:

- use the `ggnetwork` package to turn your igraph object into a dataframe
- map your clusters to the nodes present in this dataframe
- generate coordinates for the straight lines and map these to each cluster
- use `ggplot` to visualise

There is also a `hiveR` package in R, should you wish to use a packaged solution. You might also find another visualisation technique for graphs very useful: [BioFabric](http://www.biofabric.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much these graphs look really informative my experience isn't high enough that I would be able to produce something like this before my deadlines but I may try to contact you to send some example data